# Run background task while app is "onPause" Xamarin

Tags: android, multithreading, xamarin, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have an app that connect to a thermal printer, after 20-30 mins without use, the printer turn off, I need to keep the printer alive, I was thinking on sending some bytes every x mins, but when the user open another app and send my app to "sleep" the timer goes off, is there a way to send some bytes while the app is on "sleep"? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You could start an Android `Service` (foregrounded) OnPause and stop it OnResume and have the service "ping" the printer every X mins... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services Or use an Android JobScheduler to run some a "ping" routine  every 15(+) minutes.... In this case I would look at the JobScheduler as it seems more appropriate  to your use-case.

Comment: I tried with a JobSheduler, but it doesnt runs every 15 mins, it's not very consistent, I am trying with a Service now and it seems to work, I will let it run the entire day to test it, I can't  mark you comment as an answer, but thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

[JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) would be the best way to achieve your goal.

Specifically, you should specify an periodical job to awake the printer via [JobScheduler API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler).

Most importantly, you MUST ask user to whitelist your app from Battery Optimization or else the periodical jobs will be deferred due to [Android Doze Mode & App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).